# :after is overlapping main div when hovering when I use transform: scale

Tags: html, css, hover, pseudo-element

I have this button that hasthis shadow effect which is applied by using an :after pseudo element, as I want the shadow to be smaller than the main element. 
The problem is that when I apply the transform:scale property the :after comes forward and overlap the main one. Heres the code:

```css
button {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 300;
 background: inherit;
 min-width: 180px;
 max-height: 60px;
 border-radius: 30px;
 padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .btn-main {
 color:black!important;
 background: white;
    }

    .btn-main:hover {
 transform:scale(1.1)
    }


    .btn-main:after {
 content: '&nbsp;';
 opacity: .6;
 position: relative;
 top:-5px;
 background: black;
 width: 60%;
 border-radius: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 z-index: -1;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 4px rgba(144,164,174,1), 0px 0px 4px        rgba(144,164,174,1), 0px 0px 50px 30px rgba(144,164,174,.3);
    }
```

```html
<button class="btn-main">I'm a button</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been trying this for a while now and the best I can come up with is to wrap the element and use its pseudo for the shadow

```css
.btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.btn-wrapper button {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background: white;
  min-width: 180px;
  max-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.btn-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 80%;
  width: 40%;
  left: 30%;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 4px rgba(144, 164, 174, 1), 0px 0px 4px rgba(144, 164, 174, 1), 0px 0px 35px 22px rgba(144, 164, 174, .3);
}

.btn-wrapper:hover .btn-main {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.btn-wrapper:hover::before {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 12px 4px rgba(255,0,0, 1), 0px 0px 4px rgba(255,0,0, 1), 0px 0px 35px 22px rgba(255,0,0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn-main">I'm a button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but then i don't know how to change the shadow's properties as well when i hover the button

Comment: @HugoMoutinho Updated my answer to show how-to (added the new updated hover classes at the end of the CSS)

Comment: Awesome, mate. Thanks